# ReactJS assign click handler in for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi so I have this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cmrunhow/5/ and it is working fine. However I was wondering why can't I replace

```
var clickHandler = this.props.onRatingSelected && this.props.onRatingSelected.bind(null, i);
items.push(<li key={i} className={i <= this.props.value && 'filled'} onClick={clickHandler}>{'\u2605'}</li>);
```

with

```
items.push(<li key={i} className={i <= this.props.value && 'filled'} onClick={this.props.onRatingSelected.bind(null, i)}>{'\u2605'}</li>);
```

assuming I skip the sanity check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your fiddle *FundooRating* component is called **with and without** `onRatingSelected` props.

```
 <div>
  Rating is {this.state.rating} <br/>
  Clickable Rating <br/>
  <FundooRating value={this.state.rating} max="10" onRatingSelected={this.handleRatingSelected.bind(this)} />
  <br />
  Readonly rating <br/>
  <FundooRating value={this.state.rating} max="10" />
</div>
```

so you will have to check for `null` case in replaced code too

```
items.push(<li key={i} className={i <= this.props.value && 'filled'} onClick={this.props.onRatingSelected && this.props.onRatingSelected.bind(null, i)}>{'\u2605'}</li>);
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmrunhow/6/)

Comment: Just a pointer, instead of `.bind(null, i)` do `.bind(this, i)`

Comment: Ahhh yes, I was too obsessed with the first row of stars I totally neglected the second row. A quick follow up question tho, using the same fiddle with some changes here http://jsfiddle.net/cmrunhow/7/ , I realized React with ES6 no longer autobinds method and one of the alternative is to use fat arrow function. Could you take a look and tell me where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I believe fat arrow functions are not supported in ES6 classes.

Comment: To my knowledge it should have worked. There is another way of using fat arrow. http://jsfiddle.net/y944zuoc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need the check for

```
this.props.onRatingSelected
```

because you have an instance of *FundooRating* your where you don't pass a handler as a prop:

```
 <FundooRating value={this.state.rating} max="10" />
```

(just below the *Readonly* text).